# Typewriter: generate TypeScript parameter properties

Tags: typewriter

Currently I am using Typewriter for automatic generation of TypeScript class from my C# classes. Lets say I have this very simple C# class:

```
[Dto]
public class MyDto
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }

    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

Also I have this simple typewriter template:

```
$Classes(c => c.Attributes.Any(x => x.Name == "Dto"))[
export class $Name {
    constructor(
        $Properties[
            public $name: string,
        ]
    ) { }
}]
```

The issue I have with this template is that there is a trailing comma after the last constructor parameter property in the generated ts class:

```
export class MyDto {
    constructor(
            public prop1: string,
            public prop2: string,     /* <---- notice the comma here */
    ) { }
}
```

I would like to have the properties of the C# class generated as parameter properties in the TypeScript class, but with the example above the generated TypeScript is not valid. Is there a way to achieve this with a Typewriter template?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer my own question: I amended the template like this:

```
$Classes(c => c.Attributes.Any(x => x.Name == "Dto"))[
export class $Name {
    constructor(
        $Properties[
            public $name: string][,]
    ) { }
}]
```